# Derivative of the Solution to a Fixed Point Iteration

Tags: partial-derivative, fixed-point-theorems

Let $\theta_s$ is the solution to a fixed point equation $$\theta=f(\theta,\lambda)$$  Let $d(\theta,\lambda)$ be another function of $\theta,\ \lambda$. I know $f$ but I have no explicit expression for the solution $\theta_s$.  Now, if I need to evaluate $d'(\theta_s,\lambda_s)$ where the differentiation is with respect to $\lambda$, how should I proceed to do that?

Comment: What has $d$ got to do with the solution? Why would the calculation of ${ \partial d(\theta,  \lambda) \over \partial \lambda}$ have any relation to the solution of the system $f_1,f_2$?

Comment: Sorry, I feel that I have not correctly asked what I want to ask. Let me modify the question suitably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Implicit Function Theorem. Your function
$$\lambda\longmapsto\theta_s$$
is defined implicitly by
$$\theta=f(\theta,\lambda).$$
Then,
$$
\theta'(\lambda)=
{\partial f\over\partial\theta}\,\theta'(\lambda)+{\partial f\over\partial\lambda}.
$$